# How to make PHP loop refresh when clicking class tag

Tags: php

Okay so I have this portfolio page where I display a couple of thumbnails, and you can order it by tags, so for example like this:

```
<a href="#" title="year1" class="sort" onclick="reveal('year1');">year 1</a>
```

And this works fine. However, my thumbnails display at three on a row, so only the first two should have a right margin, the third one no margin. 
I used PHP to do this which works fine.

```
if ($result=$link->query($query)) {
    for ($i=1; $i <= $result->num_rows; $i++) {
    $row= $result->fetch_assoc();

    $id = $row['number'];
    $title = $row['title'];
    $bgthumbnail = $row['thumbnail'];


    if($i%3 == 0){                          
    echo "
    <div class=\"thumbnail\">
         <a href=\"portfoliodetail.php?id=$id\">
         <div class=\"thumbnailOverview noMargin\" style=\"background: url('images/portfolio/thumbnails/$bgthumbnail'); background-position: center center;\">
             <div class=\"latestWorkTitle\">$title</div>
         </div>
         </a>
    </div>
    ";

    } else {

    echo "
    <div class=\"thumbnail\">
        <a href=\"portfoliodetail.php?id=$id\">
        <div class=\"thumbnailOverview\" style=\"background: url('images/portfolio/thumbnails/$bgthumbnail'); background-position: center center;\">
            <div class=\"latestWorkTitle\">$title</div>
        </div>
        </a>
    </div>
    ";

    }

}  

$result->close();
}
```

However, when I click a tag, the margin doesn't update. So when a thumbnail was given no margin in the overview because it was the third one in row, when it displays first because of a chosen tag, it also receives no margin.

Of course this is because nothing "refreshes" or something, but I was wondering if there is an "easy" way to fix this problem? To make the PHP loop run again or something?

Comment: I'm not familiar with Ajax, but if that's the best solution I could try start looking into it.

Comment: You could try using [:nth-child() selector](http://css-tricks.com/how-nth-child-works/) in css to avoid using a custom class just for the margin

Comment: FWIW you can jump in and out of php mode `<?php ?>` which would prevent you writing that HTML using `echo`

Comment: php in this case is only 'make loop' at the begining. I'd recomend you using javascript to menage refreshing margins etc. If you want to php run again you can refresh the page but whik it is not want you want. FYI you may also think a bit about refectore this code

Comment: Why you are repeating your html twice just to add `noMargin` class? use `...... class=\"thumbnailOverview".( ( $i % 3 == 0 ) ? " noMargin" : "" )."\" styl.........` instead of repeating and save space as well as time :\

Comment: I changed my PHP code with the tips given, thanks! However, the :nth-child() selector does not work together with my PHP code? I'll look into Ajax or JavaScript.

Answer (score 0):

unless your "tags" are recalling the page - so that the php is re-executed - you probably want to look at javascript (or possibly ajax) to do the reformatting of the layout.

Depending on the quantity of thumbnails and the variety of tags, you might use the php to create a div (with a relevant id and a style="" attribute) for each of the different filter tags - containing the layout of the thumbnails for that tag (so you can ensure your layout is fine for each view).

i.e. repeat your code above enclosed by a unique div tag for each view.

Make the default view div visible (style="display: block") and the others hidden (style="dsplay: none").

Then have a javascript function that is executed on any tag click. This will make the relevant div visible and the rest hidden, by changing their style value as above.

Uses a bit more memory, but your switching between views will be quicker than doing a reload.

Despite all this, I think it's cleaner and more scalable to recall the page with the relative filter (depending on the tag) then you will have more control over the layout.

Answer (score 0):

You must to set/remove noMargin class name via javascript:

```
$('.year-clicker').click(function (event) {
    event.preventDefault();
    var year = $(event.currentTarget).data('year');
    $('.thumb').hide().removeClass('noMargin').filter('.year' + year).show();
    $('.thumb:visible').each(function (i, e) {
        if ((i + 1) % 3 == 0) {
            $(e).addClass('noMargin');
        }
    });
    return false;
});
```

Try out this jsfiddle http://jsfiddle.net/xgE3K/1/

Comment: May be, there are some decisione without javascript (css only), but it depends on markup and styles, need to view css code.